# how to know the number of requests made by a client in my web application

Tags: node.js

I developed a web application with Node.js and I want to know how many client can support my application for that I need to know the number of requests made by a single client, other way I want to know the max number of requests that a client can do .

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for tips on how to ask good questions with good examples. For this question, please share what you've already tried. For example--how do you identify a single client? A browser session? A browser tab? An IP address? A signed-in user? Etc...

Comment: thank you for your comment, I'll pay attention next time .

Comment: You don't have to wait until next time: just edit your question and add more details, and then maybe someone will be able to help.